# How to combine a bunch of Ansible playbooks which have the same slow setup and teardown?

Tags: ansible

I have about 10 playbooks which do modular things, but all of them require restarting the machine to take effect.

Is there a simple way to say "Run these 10 playbooks, but skip the restart phase in all of them, only restarting at the end"?

#### Single playbook example

```
tasks:
  - name: task1
    ...
  - name: task2
    ...
  - name: task3
    ...
  - name: Reboot machine
    become: yes
    reboot:
```

#### Attempt at combining them

```
- import_playbook: pb1.yml
- import_playbook: pb2.yml
- import_playbook: pb3.yml
...
```

#### Problem with attempted solution

There are 10 reboots of the machine, when only one is necessary, and causes the job to take much longer than it should - an hour instead of 10 minutes for some of the slower machines

A simple fix is now removing the reboots from all the singular playbooks, except this introduces a new problem in that none of the singular playbooks work now as each one individually does need that reboot for it to work.

I could copy paste everything into more playbooks and manually remove the reboots, but I don't like moving away from single source, especially since these playbooks are constantly being tweaked and updated as code changes and new system behaviors need to be addressed.

Comment: I think you might have confused the aim of an Ansible Playbook and an [Ansible Role](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_reuse_roles.html). From the pseudocode you posted, your playbooks should be reusable Ansible Roles (and maybe have playbooks that only run one role). If you change the scripts to use roles, you can then use a [handler](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_intro.html#handlers-running-operations-on-change) to do the reboot. For inspiration, you can check this [role](https://github.com/gzm55/ansible-reboot-handler-role).

Comment: Have you consider using https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_intro.html#handlers-running-operations-on-change handlers?

Comment: @manOv: simple handlers are NoGo. See "[Actions are triggered at the end of each block of tasks in a play](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_intro.html#handlers-running-operations-on-change)".

Comment: @VladimirBotka I see it and I don't see your point anyhow... his use is exactly what handlers were designed for. A reboot will occur last, after all playbooks.

Comment: @man0v happen to have a link to any simple working handler examples? I tried to figure it out and was just burning time with syntax errors and not having a good mental model of what’s actually going on.

Answer (score 0):

In each playbook add the same unique tag `my_reboot` to the reboot task, then run all  with `--skip-tags my_reboot`. Create a handler in your top level playbook, or post_tasks.

Comment: This is actually my current answer, but I don’t feel it is a good one because it involves not tagging the last reboot as a reboot, and didn’t want to tunnel vision the solutions around it. It sounds more like refactoring a bit into handlers is the way to go.

Comment: Roles and handlers are best practices. https://www.slideshare.net/bbaassssiiee/ansible-best-practices?from_m_app=ios